# Why Does Reassigning Function Pointer Slow Down Function Call

Tags: javascript, performance, pointers, benchmarking

I have been using a function pointer, `p`, to call different functions. My problem is, the performance of calling `p` decreases dramatically if I point it to a different function after it has already been assigned a function. The performance is fine if I switch `p` between `undefined` and the same function over and over again, and fine when I only point it to one function, but switching between functions kills performance.

Below is the code I am using to test this scenario and here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjfu9ye2/40/). I loop 500 times recursively and call `p` 1,000,000 times on each loop. `p` can be `undefined` or pointing to `func1` or `func2`.

```
function func1() {} // two identical empty functions
function func2() {} // different in name only

var p = func1; // default to func1

var count  = 0; // current loop
var elapse = 0; // elapsed time for 1,000,000 calls on each loop
var start  = 0; // start time for 1,000,000 calls on each loop
var total  = 0; // total elapsed time for all loops

function loop() {

  start = performance.now(); // get start time

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) if (p !== undefined) p(); // do 1,000,000 calls or early out 1,000,000 times if undefined

    elapse = performance.now() - start;

  total += elapse; // used for getting average

  count ++;

  console.log(p + "\nelapsed " + elapse + "\naverage " + total / count);

  // Switch between the lines below to see the performance difference.
  p = (p === func1) ? p = undefined : p = func1; // best performance
  //p = (p === func1) ? p = func1 : p = func1; // good performance
  //p = (p === func1) ? p = func2 : p = func1; // bad performance

  // pattern: func1 -> undefined -> func2 -> undefined -> repeat
  /*if (p === undefined) p = (count % 4 === 0) ? p = func1 : p = func2;
  else p = undefined;*/ // also bad performance

  if (count < 500) loop(); // start the next loop

}

console.clear();

loop(); // start the loop
```

Why does the performance of calling `p` drop significantly when it is assigned a different function? Also, why does setting `p` to `undefined` and back to the original function not change performance when setting `p` to `undefined` and then to a different function does?

Comment: The JIT compiler caches things.

Comment: So setting it to undefined doesn't reset the cache? And the majority of the performance lost is due to the memory rewrite? But then why doesn't the cache happen at reassignment and then 1,000,000 calls use the updated cache? Or does the caching only happen at compilation?

Comment: The fact that you're running this test using recursion instead of a for loop might affect things

Comment: That's a good point, but I get the same results when using window.requestAnimationFrame to run the loop.

Comment: @Frank The cache invalidation probably happens when you *call* the function. You never call the function when it's set to `undefined`, so it doesn't invalidate it.

Comment: By repeatedly changing which function the pointer points to, you're messing with the runtime predictor for guessing which function the pointer is actually pointing to. Prediction is a huge part of performance, and by messing with that, you are observing the consequences.

Comment: Which browser? what have you measured?

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome and I'm measuring a difference of about 17ms between best case and worst case. The cases where I set the pointer to undefined can be omitted. I may try calling the function once before I enter the for loop in order to test @Barmar 's suggestion on invalidation or maybe skip a loop after the change to give the cache time to catch up. Not really sure how it works.

Comment: [Google javascript v8 engine optimizations](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+v8+engine+optimizations&oq=javascript+v8+engine+optimizations&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4359j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) It might be answered somewhere in these sites.

Comment: Even if I call p once while it points to func1 and then assign it to func2 and call it again before starting the loop, there is still a performance loss of about 2.5 ms on Chrome. If the cache has been reset, I don't understand the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stopping the engine from creating an optimized hotpath because it can't rely on the value of the function pointer.

See the section titled "Interpreter/compiler pipelines in JavaScript engines" in this article: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shapes-ics

The pictures show TurboFan optimizing the bytecode based on profiling data from execution, and the text after it explains:

> To make it run faster, the bytecode can be sent to the optimizing compiler along with profiling data. The optimizing compiler makes certain assumptions based on the profiling data it has, and then produces highly-optimized machine code.
>
> If at some point one of the assumptions turns out to be incorrect, the optimizing compiler deoptimizes and goes back to the interpreter.

When you reassign the function pointer, you send conflicting profiling data from the interpreter to the compiler. This doesn't happen when you assign undefined, because that code path doesn't get executed in that case: `if (p !== undefined) p();`

Comment: Then why does assigning undefined run faster?

Comment: Because nothing executes when it is undefined, and the hot path is not disrupted.

Comment: If you are running this in V8 (e.g: Node or Chrome), then TurboFan will get conflicting profiling data when different functions are executed. See here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shapes-ics

Comment: If you would extract the noteworthy parts of that article into your answer, it could actually answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, the tests with undefined are skipping the function call all together. I just put them in there to see what would happen if I set the pointer to undefined before reassigning it. My thought process was that if there were something like a "hot path" it would be refreshed if I set the value to undefined, but that is clearly not the case and not how it works.

Comment: Even if I call `p` once while it points to `func1` and then assign it to `func2` and call it again before starting the loop, there is still a performance loss of about 2.5 ms on Chrome. If the cache has been reset, I don't understand the loss.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if I call p once while it points to func1 and then assign it to func2 and call it again before starting the loop, there is still a performance loss of about 2.5 ms on Chrome. If the cache has been reset, I don't understand the loss.

Your mental model of V8 isn't accurate.  It can JIT-compile JS to native machine code in some conditions, but anything it can't handle will "de-optimize" the whole function (or block or loop?) and make it interpreted.

I'm not much of an expert on JS or V8, but I've picked up some details.  Google found this:
https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8

**So it's not that you're invalidating "the cache" once, you're removing an invariant condition that it was optimizing based on.**

---

Branch prediction as a cache for branch targets only matters once you get your JS runtime to JIT to native machine code instead of interpreting.  When interpreting, control dependencies in the JS are merely data dependencies in the interpreter running on the native CPU.

If removing this invariant de-optimizes the function, or the hot loop, then that's your problem, not branch prediction.